# When I put my buttons on div CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to buttons auto middle on page, but I can't bec of when I put buttons on div, they doesnt work. thanks for helping

```css
   *:focus{
      outline:0px;
   }
   body{
      width:100%;
   }
   .buttons{
      width:200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
       
   .tr,.eu{
      width:65px;height:30px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-color:transparent;
      background-color:#00405d;
      color:white;
      font-weight:500;
   }
   .tr:active,.eu:active{
      padding:3px;
   }

   .EU {display: none;}

   .eu:focus ~ .TR {display: none;}
   .tr:focus ~ .TR {display: block;}
   .tr:focus ~ .EU {display: none;}
   .eu:focus ~ .EU {display: block;}
```

```html
first 2 buttons
<button type="button" class="eu" name="button">EU</button> Working
<button type="button" class="tr" name="button">TR</button> Working
first 2 buttons
<br>
<br>

other 2 buttons in div
      <!--but doesnt work  bec of in div -->
      <div>
         <button type="button" class="eu" name="button">EU</button>doesnt work on div
         <button type="button" class="tr" name="button">TR</button>doesnt work on div
      </div>
      <!--but doesnt work bec of in div -->
other 2 buttons in div

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      
RESULT:
      <div class="TR">
         tr
      </div>
      <div class="EU">
         eu
      </div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What means "doesn't work"?

Comment: when i click first buttons, result is changing but i click second buttons(in div) result isnt changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following css rule to your codes

```
button.eu,
button.tr {
  border: solid red;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
#btn_container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Snippet below

```js
var eu_btns = document.getElementsByClassName("eu");
var tr_btns = document.getElementsByClassName("tr");
var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("TR")[0];
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName("EU")[0];
for (var x = 0; x < eu_btns.length; ++x) {
  eu_btns[x].addEventListener("click", eu_click)
}
for (var x = 0; x < tr_btns.length; ++x) {
  tr_btns[x].addEventListener("click", tr_click)
}

function eu_click() {
  div2.style.display = "inline-block";
  div1.style.display = "none";

}

function tr_click() {
  div1.style.display = "inline-block";
  div2.style.display = "none";

}
```

```css
*:focus {
  outline: 0px;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.buttons {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tr,
.eu {
  width: 65px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #00405d;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.EU {
  display: none;
}
.eu:focus ~ .TR {
  display: none;
}
.tr:focus ~ .TR {
  display: block;
}
.tr:focus ~ .EU {
  display: none;
}
.eu:focus ~ .EU {
  display: block;
}
button.eu,
button.tr {
  border: solid red;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
#btn_container {
  position: relative;
}
.TR,
.EU {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="tr" name="button">TR</button>
<!--working -->

<!--but doesnt work  bec of in div -->
<div id="btn_container">
  <button type="button" class="eu" name="button">EU</button>
  <button type="button" class="tr" name="button">TR</button>
</div>
<!--but doesnt work bec of in div -->

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="TR">
  tr
</div>
<div class="EU">
  eu
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help i tried but doesnt work.
it wasnt working on snippet, too
also thank you than

Comment: it works in your code sample you provided..see the snippet....you want to buttons to be in the center of the page right?

Comment: yes, but when i click the "working" buttons, "results" is changing.
but in this code, its doesnt work too

Comment: okay...I believe there was a padding rule on when the button was in an active state..so I updated my snippet...hmm....can you explain what "result"s is changing?

Comment: yes please check again my code, i updated. first 2 buttons is working when i click and my div.TR and div.EU class showing. but after 2 buttons ( its mean buttons inside div) they doesnt work.(its mean; result divs, doesnt work)

Comment: sorry my bad english, i think i cant tell you what i want.
i just want buttons on middle, and toggle work. just it, 
when i click button 1, it must be show me div1 and hide div2.
when i click button 2, it must be show me div2 and hide div. of course on the upper buttons in the middle

Comment: Welcome Friend :D